# What controls version number inside codedom generated file?

Tags: c#, versioning, codedom

**What controls the version number inside of a codedom generated file?**

Some of our developers get:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:2.0.50727.4005
```

while others get:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:2.0.50727.3082
```

But everyone seems to be running .Net 3.5 SP1.

**Why do some have 4005 and others have 3082 as the build number?**

This is a real pain for source control.

Comment: This number *may* be based on the version of C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll you have.

Answer (score 1):

Although everyone is running .NET 3.5 SP1, they won't be running the exact same versions of .NET 3.5 SP1. Specifically, they will be running different precise builds for whatever reason. I would suspect OS differences, or just laziness with Windows updates.

Comment: Correct: the .NET bits built into Vista or Win7, for instance, are going to have a different revision # than the general release.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,

Everyone is running XP and every one seems to be completely up to date with their Windows Updates.

Does anyone know which file/assembly is responsible for the versioning of CodeDom?

Answer (score 1):

Patches (such as minor bug fixes delivered through Windows Update) are the one to "blame" for.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's quick fixes, some of them download and install automatically if you left windows autoupdate settings at default.
If it really is causing problems, then you might pass a readme or some kind of policy for everyone to know, which version you are using right now. But if olny the last numbers are different, that means it just contains bugfixes, which fortunately rarely breaks funcionality. Except for workaround code, and hacks intended to bypass or fix those framework bugs which just got fixed ...